# Error when clone existing Android project from github

Tags: java, android, gradle, github

I need to clone my existing android project from github to another computer but while i cloning my repo android studio giving me such error. what can i do for successful cloning my project?

My Module.app file is bwllow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

and the error is

[image]

Comment: did you try `Invalidate Cache/Restart` ?

Comment: the exact problem is for unresolved dependency.

Comment: git clone @stud3nt

Answer (score 1):

Press double shift and type offline work. 
You can go there via. Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.
Could you see if you have offline work enabled. If that is the case disable it and try again.

Comment: offline work already disabled

Comment: Can you post the top level gradle file. Want to see that,